# Can someone working with a law enforcement agency "get away" with a speeding ticket if is required ASAP on a location?

Tags: united-states, california, speeding

On the episode [Red Alert](https://thementalist.fandom.com/wiki/Red_Alert) (S03E13) of the show The Mentalist, [CBI](https://thementalist.fandom.com/wiki/California_Bureau_of_Investigation) (like the FBI, but only for CA) Consultant Patrick Jane gets stopped by a police officer on it's way to a crime scene because he was going 13mph over the speed limit. He shows his badge as proof that he is working for the CBI to try and persuade the officer, but he still gives him a ticket.

If this were to happen in the real world, would it would be possible for him to "get away" with the ticket in the state of California? He was needed as soon as possible by an actual LEO for an active investigation and is working for a state agency, but he is not legally an LEO.

Comment: If I genuinely felt that my presence was needed ASAP (e.g., only I can prevent Dr. Evil from destroying the world), then I simply would not stop for the police officer.  That Jane stopped for the officer shows that his CBI assignment was not really that urgent.

Comment: If society felt that my presence was needed ASAP (e.g., President Biden has ordered me to prevent Dr. Evil from destroying the world) then I would have a police escort clearing other cops out of my path.

Comment: emory, depending on the cars involved, stopping and accepting the ticket may be the fastest way to get to your destination.

Comment: Fun fact: Jane stopped but didn't wanted to accept the ticket so he ran off from the police officer. He was still handed the ticket later.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Law enforcement officers have a wide latitude when dealing with someone who is not following the law; in general they cannot issue you a fine if you are not speeding but they are not required to issue a fine if you are speeding.

So if the LEO decides for whatever the reason that you do not deserve a ticket even if you were driving sobre the speed limit, he ello not issue it and that would be the end of it.

Now if the officer issues the ticket, there is recourse. The most simple would be simply to forward additional evidence to the police department, even informally, to see if they rethink about it and void the ticket on their own.

If they still refuse, there are always procedures to legally challenge a ticket, which may depend based on the jurisdiction and even the kind or amount of sanction. In general I would expect that it goes that far and you can show that it was indeed an emergency, even in the absence of a specific law a judge would invalidate the fine because it would go against the public interest.

And if even that does not work, you may probably ask for a pardon.

Comment: The process of legally challenging a ticket usually looks like (or actually is) a bench trial in front of a judge or quasi-judge.  There are niceties like if the officer doesn't show up, you get off.  Which wouldn't necessarily happen in a pure civil trial. The judge also has a lot of latitude, and the state either can't appeal, or is vanishingly unlikely to.

Comment: I think this has to do with separation of federal and state powers in the US context.  If the speeder was performing federal duties, then the process would be to challenge the jurisdiction of the state court to hear the speeding ticket.  Once found lacking jurisdiction the ticket would be of no further concern.  I imagine the process would be similar in Canada.